# What is the meaning of streamlined ipv6 header?

Tags: ipv6

I don't understand what it is meant for "streamlined ipv6 header"?
Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*IPv4* has a lot of fields (14) in the header:

- Version
- IHL: Internet Header Length.
- DSCP: Type of Service.
- ECN: Explicit Congestion Notification.
- Total Length: Length of entire IP Packet.
- Identification: An identification number for fragmented packets.
- Flags
- Fragment Offset: Position of the fragment in the original Packet.
- Time to Live.
- Protocol: Next level Protocol. (UDP, TCP, etc.).
- Header Checksum
- Source Address
- Destination Address
- Options

[image]

*IPV6* designers have reduced this complexity (**streamlined the header**) to make it easier for routers and network systems to verify each packet and forward it using a routing table.

The IPV6 header has the following 8 fields:

- Version
- Traffic Class: 8-bits, the most significant 6 bits are Type of Service and the remaining 2 are used for Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN).
- Flow Label: Used to maintain the sequential flow of the packets belonging to a communication. The source labels the sequence to help the router identify that a particular packet belongs to a specific flow of information. This field helps avoid re-ordering of data packets. It is designed for streaming/real-time media.
- Payload Length: Payload is composed of Extension Headers and Upper Layer data.
- Next Header: Indicates either the type of Extension Header, or if the Extension Header is not present then it indicates the Upper Layer.
- Hop Limit: This is the same as TTL on IPv4.
- Source Address (128-bits).
- Destination Address (128-bits).

The IPv6 header format was designed to keep the header overhead to a minimum.

The non-essential fields and optional fields were moved to extension headers that are placed after the IPv6 header. The IPv6 header  can be processed more efficiently at intermediate routers.